# LinkedList in java,is it possible to make elements number counting method using recursion?

Tags: java

The problem is the same as my title. I am now studying the data structure and struggling with the problem. the LinkedList now has a dummy head and it is impossible to make another global variable.

```
public int numItems() {
 just here is the all I can modify.
}
```

I think that to solve this problem using recursion, there must be an argument for the method. But as I am a Noob coder, I am not sure about my opinion.

I tried the first method with no arguments and it calls another method with arguments like

```
public int numItems() { 
  return numItems(head);
}

public int numItems(Node node) {
  if(node.next == null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1 + numItems(node.next); 
  }
}
```

using Java's method of overloading. but this too is not a proper answer to this question.
So, if you have any idea that can code the counting of the number of the elements in LinkedList using recursion, please let me know... or if it is impossible also please tell me that it is not possible.

Comment: Sure you can use recursion.  You can also use iterations: there are pros/cons either way.  In any case, your solution looks OK.  In particular, it's perfectly legitimate to overload "numItems()" with "numItems(Node node)", as you've done in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve by accumulating the count on each node travel.

```
public int numItems(Node node, int accumulator){
    if(node == null){
        return accumulator; 
    }

    return numItems(node.next, 1 + accumulator)
}

numItems(node, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively count the number of elements in your linked list by starting at your first actual node and not in a "hypothetical" head.

Your end-result should look something like this:

```java
public int numItems() {
    return numItems(head.next); // start at the first actual node
}

private int numItems(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + numItems(node.next);
}
```

And you don't need any [method overloading](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java) for this problem .

Comment: Thank you! Then is it impossible to code this method(recursion) not using java's overloading? Just in one method ->  public int numItems()

Comment: You do not need overloading for recursion. You can use any name you want for the private recursive method.

Comment: @Noob Coder: 1) your example is fine. 2) You *DON'T* need overloading, if you don't want it. 3) One alternative is to give the recursive method a different name. 4) Another alternative is to iterate through the list (counting each node) instead of using recursion at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of clarifications to ask here:

- Is `numItems` method of `LinkedList`?
- It is not the best practice, but is it okay or is it possible in your case to mutate the `dummy head`?

```
public int numItems() {
    if (null == this.dummyHead) {
        return 0;
    }
    this.dummyHead = this.dummyHead.next;
    return 1 + this.numItems();
}
```

Note: It is not a production like practice, but solves the case within your limitations.

Update: there is possibly off by one if we don't want `dummyHead` to be counted in. In that case if we are guaranteed to have the `dummyHead` all the time, then instead of `0` in the `null check` we should return `-1` instead to be precise.